# "Select "Import from existing model- Gradle" " - Whaaa?

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play-services

I was reading the instructions on how to run a Google Play services sample in Android Studio (Particularly ButtonClicker2000), and saw that step 5 says: "Select "Import from existing model - Gradle"" what does Google mean by this? Where can I find this element to select?

Thanks in advance!

Here is the page I was reading it from: https://github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you have selected a folder to import as an Android Studio project in the next step you will be presented with a dialog that allows you to select how to import the project.  'Import from external model - Gradle' is one of the options. I believe the instructions you are following have a typo and it should read 'external' rather than 'existing'.

[image: import from Gradle]